# How to get a line like the pic instead of \rule{6cm}

Tags: rules

I was making a template for thesis and this looked better than \rule. How to get this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one appears to be an ellipse with a nontrivial color gradient.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
 \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{HarvardLogo.jpg}\\%https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKYwS.jpg
 \hspace{0.5cm}\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5\textwidth]
  \draw[outer color=black,inner color=gray!60!black] circle[x radius=0.5,y radius=0.05];
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
Perhaps nicer:

\hfill\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5\textwidth]
\draw[outer color=black,inner color=gray] circle[x radius=0.5,y radius=0.05];
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill\mbox{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The uppermost is from your screenshot and the lower ones are attempts to reproduce the "rule" with Ti*k*Z.